# Double load needed for execfile

Tags: python

I'm making my own command prompt-like program. For now, the addon part is done but one little issue, I'm loading the addon .py scripts through execfile() and to make the plugin work you need to do it 2 times and that is pretty annoying.
Here is the code:

```
import os
from past.builtins import execfile
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
mypath = "plugins"
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]
lengthfiles = len(onlyfiles)
quitcommand = ["exit", "quit"]
loopnumber = 0
print("eh")
while True:
    cmd = input("plugcmd> ")
    if cmd in quitcommand:
        exit("Quitting the shell...")
        continue
    for i in range(0,lengthfiles):
        execfile("plugins/" + str(onlyfiles[i]))
```

and the plugins im trying to load

```
from main import cmd
epiccommands = "test"
if cmd == "test":
    print("epic")
```

Comment: Any specific reason why you're using `execfile` instead of importing the "plugin"? Simply use `importlib`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module

Comment: @l4mpi i got ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plugins/test'
edit: i just realised its used for importing like the normal ```import```, sorry but i need it to be like in the while True: loop so it can do output

Comment: The ModuleNotFoundError could be caused by not having an `__init__.py` in the plugins directory. And if you want to repeatedly execute the code in each plugin module in a loop, there are multiple ways to do so, for example defining a `run()` method in each plugin which contains the code you want do run. Then you can import the plugin with `importlib.import_module` and call `run()` on the returned module object. Using `exec`, and by extension `execfile`, is a usually a sign of bad design... let's just say there's reasons why it was removed in python3.